# typeerror missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, command-line-arguments, positional-argument

I tried to do Portfolio optimization, but then the `TypeError: minimize_sharpe() missing 1 required positional argument: 'log_returns'` appeared: Please find the extract below.

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize 
optimal_sharpe=optimize.minimize(minimize_sharpe,
                                 initializer,
                                 method = 'SLSQP',
                                 bounds = bounds,
                                 constraints = constraints)
print(optimal_sharpe)
```

The definition of "minimize_sharpe comes with the following code

```
def minimize_sharpe(weights, log_returns):  
return -portfolio_stats(weights)['Sharpe']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think args needs to be referenced like this. The example that you are referring to may also not be passing returns to the portfolio_stats function.

```
def minimize_sharpe(weights, returns):  
    return -portfolio_stats(weights,returns)['sharpe'] 

import scipy.optimize as optimize
optimal_sharpe=optimize.minimize(minimize_sharpe,
                                 initializer,
                                 args = (returns,),
                                 method = 'SLSQP',
                                 bounds = bounds,
                                 constraints = constraints)
```